# Book for writing scalable web-applications/web-serivces

Tags: java, web-services, spring, web-applications, scalability

please can you suggest me a good book about writing scalable web-application/web-services (possible using Spring framework tho not mandatory)?

Thank you very much

Randomize

Comment: this is a great question, no code fragment in there, doesn't make it any bit less than other questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Books:

- [The Art of Scalability: Scalable Web Architecture, Processes, and Organizations for the Modern Enterprise](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0137030428)
- [The Art of Capacity Planning: Scaling Web Resources](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596518579)
- [Scalability Rules: 50 Principles for Scaling Web Sites](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321753887)

The following links are not books but presentation slides that might be helpful as well:

- [Successfully Scaling Java Applications in Spring](http://www.nejug.org/events/download?f=41)  (based on Oracle product)
- [Scaling Spring Applications in 4 Easy Steps](http://www.gigaspaces.com/viewpdf/861) (based on Open Source product OpenSpaces)

Answer (score 0):

I have "Scalable Internet Architectures" by Theo Schlossnagle . Its a good read to understand the big picture.